# Cannot Deserialize to a c# List, returns no data using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

My json data looks as follows.

```
[
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"GasSafetyRenew",
      "dtReportDate":"2021-12-14T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":325,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Normal"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"BoilerMaintDueDate",
      "dtReportDate":"2021-12-14T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":325,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Normal"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"TenancyExpiration",
      "dtReportDate":"2022-06-30T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":523,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Normal"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"RentProtExpiry",
      "dtReportDate":"2021-07-20T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":178,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Normal"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"LegalProtectionDate",
      "dtReportDate":"2021-07-01T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":159,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Normal"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"BoilerGuaranteeDate",
      "dtReportDate":"2026-02-04T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":1838,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Normal"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"InsuranceRenewBy",
      "dtReportDate":"2020-08-24T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":-152,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Overdue"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"HMOLicenceExpiry",
      "dtReportDate":"2020-01-01T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":-388,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Overdue"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"Tenancy Expiry",
      "dtReportDate":"2020-07-05T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":-202,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Overdue"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"FireCertRenew",
      "dtReportDate":"2020-01-01T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":-388,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Overdue"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"FireServiceRenew",
      "dtReportDate":"2020-01-01T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":-388,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Overdue"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"EmergencyLightingRenew",
      "dtReportDate":"2020-01-01T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":-388,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Overdue"
   },
   {
      "nPropertyID":1,
      "sAddress_1":"1 Clean Street",
      "sReportField":"FixedEndDate",
      "dtReportDate":"2024-09-30T00:00:00",
      "nDaysToGo":1346,
      "cReminder":"Y",
      "cValid":"Y",
      "sStatus":"Normal"
   }
]
```

This I believe to be a standard json array.

My c# class is as follows:

```
 public class Reminder
    {
      
        public int nPropertyID { get; set; }
        public string sAddress_1 { get; set; }
        public string sReportField { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtReportDate { get; set; }
        public int nDaysToGo { get; set; }
        public string cReminder { get; set; }
        public string cValid { get; set; }
        public string sStatus { get; set; }

    }
```

First I return the data  as a string which is fine.
I want to deserialize to my variable 'reminders' which is a List.
I have tried to deserialize this with:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

settings.DateFormatString = "dd-MM-yyyyThh:mm:ss";

settings.Error = HandleDeserializerError;

reminders =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reminder>>(json, settings);
```

I am not getting an error.  It just returns null.

Comment: Your date format does not match the JSON's date format at all. It should be `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"`

Comment: Are you **sure** your `json` variable is not null?

Comment: can you add the `HandleDeserializerError` delegate?

Comment: Sweeper, you are right about the date format string.  I have changed it to what you suggest but it still crashes. I have also tried the format without the single quotes, but still the same result.

Comment: @Sajid, thanks for your suggestion, I have added the error handler. There is too much output  to put in this comment but basically it  is giving a type conversion problem, but difficult for me to tell where it's pointing.  The relevant part if the message is: "line 1, position 30878. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xPropertyMinder.Property]. "  Position 30878 is beyond the end of the string so it doesn't help.

Comment: @RichardSmith you're welcome! you can add `HandleDeserializerError ` by updating the question not in the comment. because we will help us to reproduce the same thing :)

Comment: I have done some more testing. I took the string returned from the api, and pasted it into a literal string which I then used in place of the string returned from the http client.  The only thing I had to change was changing double quotes into single quotes.

Comment: The deserialization then worked.  Do I conclude from this that the deserializer does not like double quotes in the string?